# Exception for escaping a character in search query/string

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, search

I need to add an exception to Magento's search to allow slashes `/` instead of escaping them to %252F - both in the search field and URL.

For example, a search for 'LIF-100/CC' currently gets converted to 'LIF-100%2FCC' (URL: /catalogsearch/result?q=LIF-100%252FCC), modifying the URL manually to '/catalogsearch/result?q=LIF-100/cc' gives the desired results.

I've got as far as the function `getQueryText` and am trying to figure out whether the following is what I'm after for this...

```
$this->_queryText = is_array($this->_queryText) ? ''
    : $stringHelper->cleanString(trim($this->_queryText));
```

I've tried various ways of removing the clean string / trimming from the above with no success (search query is always the same) so am wondering whether I should be looking at the function `prepareResult` instead?

Or should I be in fact searching for where the generation of the URL is formed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, numerous hours later I've almost got a solution to this.

Edit: Now have got a solution, make sure you read the updates at the bottom of answer.

Probably will prove very useful to any stores that require SKU codes to be searchable or have a number of products that contain special characters because now at last, by implementing the below, Magento's search will return results for these search queries.

After some debugging, I identified that the URL's were being encoded (twice) in `Url.php` located at `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model`.

```
$query = http_build_query($params, '', $escape ? '&amp;' : '&');
```

As pointed out in function `getSearchUrl` in `/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Term.php`.

```
public function getSearchUrl($obj)
{
    $url = Mage::getModel('core/url');
    /*
    * url encoding will be done in Url.php http_build_query
    * so no need to explicitly called urlencode for the text
    */
    $url->setQueryParam('q', $obj->getName());
    return $url->getUrl('catalogsearch/result');
}
```

So at this point, I knew I needed to reverse `urlencode` and output this result instead of the escaped query for search.

I was able to reverse this process using the following:-

```
$noescape = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($this->_queryText));
```

Adding this to function `getQueryText` in `/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Helper/Data.php` then allowed me to return the non escaped query text with `$noescape` so I simply add a new function in `Data.php` underneath `getEscapedQueryText` like so:-

```
/**
 * Retrieve search query without escaping special characters
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getNoEscapedQueryText()
{
    return $noescape;
}
```

Now all I need to do is figure what code is outputting the query in the URL so I can modify this to use `$noescape` but struggling to find this at present. Will update my answer as soon as I find it.

### Update

I know that `return $this->_queryText;` is what is outputting the search query in the URL now, I just haven't figured out how to incorporate the above into this output (I haven't managed to figure out the correct syntax).

Currently fiddling about with variations of

```
return $this->preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($this->_queryText));
```

and

```
return $noescape($this->_queryText);
```

## Update 2

`$noescape` above can now be ignored as we can just modify `return $this->_queryText;` directly with:-

```
return $this->_queryText = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($this->_queryText));
```

End result is that we can now use special characters in Magento's search field that returns results and doesn't escape them to %252F2 for example. The URL's will still contain the likes of %252F2 but it retains the special characters in the search field via `getQueryText` so it still resolves the problem.